# How to say "Next 'ANY_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK'"?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

Couldn't find the answer here, so I thought it would be a nice and easy question.

Which would be the right way to say "Next 'ANY_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK'"?
Eg: Next Monday?

次の月曜日 is fine? Are there any other ways to say it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 来週の月曜日 would work. I'd be interested to know if people see a difference between that and 次の月曜日

Comment: @user3856370 Nice suggestion! What about of 来月曜日？ Would that work?

Comment: @user3856370:  But the next <day of the week> may not be next week.  So using 来週 may not be true.  https://youtu.be/71nvWNAvZfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, 来週の月曜日 for example would be the most common. And it would be used to mean "the monday of next week" whereas 次の月曜日 would be used to mean "next monday" so there is a slight nuance.

次の月曜日 means next monday as I said, so it can be next monday from any week (the current one or next one). 来週の月曜日 specifically means that it is the monday from next week that we are talking about.

来月曜日 however is not used.

It is the same for "previous week". (先週の月曜日　and not 先月曜日)

Comment: And if want to say 'Last Friday'? Similar to 次の月曜日, how would it be?

Comment: 前の金曜日 is the most common one to say Last Friday. (repost: fix typo)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments and @SensitiveTesticle's answer, in colloquial Japanese, it's more frequent to say 来週の月曜日, meaning Monday of the next week. 翌週{よくしゅう}の月曜日, 次週{じしゅう}の月曜日, 明{あ}くる週の月曜日 meaning Monday of the following week, can also be used.

There are some phrases meaning "Next ...". For example, Next Monday can be translated into:

- 次の月曜日：the following Monday. This is more common both in spoken and written languages than the following phrases except for limited contexts.
- 翌{よく}月曜日：the following Monday. This is used mainly in written language, especially on business hours signs.
- 来{きた}る月曜日：next Monday. This is used in formal language (possibly outdated), both spoken and written forms. Ancient texts could write this as 来月曜日.
- 明{あ}くる月曜日：the following Monday. The nuance is similar to 来{きた}る月曜日.

The final 日 in each phrase can be omitted.